# Using a function to find the minimum of three values

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
double minimum(double x, double y, double z) {
    double temp = 0;

    //Logic here

}
int main(void) {
    double x, y, z, minVal;

    printf("Please enter three numeric values: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &x, &y, &z);
    minVal = minimum(x, y, z);
    printf("minimum(%0.10f, %0.10f, %0.10f) = %0.10f\n", x, y, z, minVal);

    return 0;
}
```

Logic of the code should go within comment in first function. Function should then result in minVal and printed too console

Comment: "i have tried many solutions, but i cannot seem to return the correct result." - Can you show us your best attempt please and we'll help you debug it? All you really need is `if`, `<` and `return`, or maybe `&&`, or maybe the ternary operators too.

Comment: Can you do a little bit of research before asking a very basic question like this ?

Comment: I think you've got your function declaration wrong too. Were you trying to use K&R style? (Don't.) And you need a return type too, not void. You probably want `double minimum(double x, double y, double z)` and then you don't need to redeclare them inside the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

double minimum(double x, double y, double z)
{
  double temp = 0;

  if (isnan(x) || isnan (y) || isnan(z))
    return NAN;

  temp = (x < y) ? x : y;
  return (temp < z)? temp : z;
}

int main(void) {
    double x, y, z, minVal;

    printf("Please enter three numeric values: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &x, &y, &z);
    minVal = minimum(x, y, z);
    printf("minimum(%0.10f, %0.10f, %0.10f) = %0.10f\n", x, y, z, minVal);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works for defined values but you should also ensure that `NaN` is returned if any of `x`, `y` or `z` is `NaN`.

Comment: @chqrlie Updated accordingly.

Comment: for portability, you should not use `NAN` which may not be available on all platforms. Either return `x + y + z` which will evaluate to `NaN` or return `nan("")`

Comment: A common use of NAN with such _minimum_ problems to it ignore that value from consideration so `min(1.0, 2.0, NAN)` --> `min(1.0, 2.0)` etc.

Comment: FWIW the spec in [the original revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51821546/1) was: min(x,y,z) should equal one of x, y and z; min(x,y,z) is less than or equal to all of x, y and z. Which would exclude NaNs, since they can't satisfy either of those.

Answer (score 1):

**method for double**:

```
int main(void)
{
     double a, b, c, temp, min;

     printf ("Enter three nos. separated by spaces: ");
     scanf ("%lf%lf%lf", &a, &b, &c);

     temp = (a < b)    ? a : b;
     min =  (c < temp) ? c : temp;

     printf ("The Minimum of the three is: %lf", min);

     /* indicate success */
     return 0;
 }
```

**method for int**:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, temp, min;

    printf ("Enter three nos. separated by spaces: ");
    scanf ("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);

    temp = (a < b)    ? a : b;
    min =  (c < temp) ? c : temp;

    printf ("The Minimum of the three is: %d", min);

    /* indicate success */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to handle floating point values... Furthermore, you should test the return value of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have return type double for the minValue function

Then your logic should be
Consider 3 numbers `a`, `b`, `c` and another `double temp`
Then...

```
If (a < b)

Temp = a

Else

Temp = b

If(temp < c)

Return temp

Else 

Return c
```